# Whmpress- How to display contents of specific group using price table shortcode

Tags: wordpress

I am using Whmpress to sync Wordpress & WHMCS .Need to display contents of specific group using the [whmpress_price_table] short code.Using the sort code '[whmpress_price_table currency="" name="" group="Magento Dedicated Servers" billingcycles="monthly" decimals="0" show_hidden="No" replace_zero="x" replace_empty="-" table_id="" type="product" html_id="" html_class="" hide_search="Yes"]'.Where 'Magento Dedicated Servers'is a group at VPS/Servers.

Answer (score 0):

Contact author at
http://codecanyon.net/user/creativeon#contact

They are good on support.